# How to compare value.val() with regex in search fields? Want to have multiple words as criterion

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, search, filter

just going crazy. I have this code, which works super:

HTML:

> `<p class="no-result"> Nothing found. </p>`

JS: (JQuery)

```
$("#itemSearch").on("keyup", function () {

  if ($("#itemSearch").val() == '') {
    $(".main").show();
  }

  else {

        $(".item").filter(function () {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(value) > -1)

          if ($(".item").text().toLowerCase().includes(value)) {
            $(".no-result").css("display", "none");
          }
          else {
            $(".no-result").css("display", "inline");
          }

        }); 
  }
});
```

But the Code shows me just ONE Item as value. I want the option to search for more than one word. So I thought about a code like this:

```
    var pattern = /^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i;
    var value = pattern.test($(this).val().trim().toLowerCase().split(" "));
```

Split for searching for more than one word/value. But am not sure that regex is necessary. What am doing wrong?

Greetings
Erya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to use the [global modifier 'g'](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_global.asp) in your regex to find multiple matches.  You also have to use `text.match(pattern)` instead of `pattern.test(text)` to retrieve an array of results.

Using

```
const pattern = /([A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})/ig;
const text= 'a@a.com  b@b.com  c@c.com';
return text.match(pattern);
```

I get an array of 3 matches:

```
[ "a@a.com", "b@b.com", "c@c.com" ]
```

No need for the .split() function, and also trimming can be skipped. You should use:

```
var value = $(this).val().match(pattern);
```